# How to describe/define tail of a distribution

Tags: distributions, descriptive-statistics

I have a histogram showing a distribution with a long tail, and I would like to come up with a definition (in words) for the points fall inside the "tail", not based on quantile or standard deviation, but by fatness of the part of the tail they are in.

In other words, I would like to draw a line on the "frequency" axis of my histogram that is for example 10% of the level of the peak.  Then describe all points whose frequency falls below that 10%, rather than as is more usual, drawing a line on the value axis (or working with a cumulative frequency plot).

My attempt so far is to say

```
"all points in bins for which the frequency (as currently binned) is under 10% of the modal peak"
```

Is there a better way of putting this?

Comment: With this definition there will be distributions that would consist of tail only (the really flat ones), so they'll become snakes...

Comment: Good point mathematically though it falls down on the zoological side - sorry I couldn't find better reference but http://www.lbc.co.uk/do-snakes-have-tails-7549

Comment: On the maths side: i'm not looking for a universal definition, just a way to properly describe this part of this particular distribution (which has a big peak) in words.

Comment: But "fatness" is arbitrary, so will be the criterion based on it.

Comment: Well, "distribution density" is arbitrary inasmuch as it depends on smoothing.  Or the bin size, to put it another way.  Will amend the above to reflect this: the question remains is there a better way to say this?

Comment: You smooth a data, not a distribution. Distribution density if precise and possible to estimate.

Comment: I'd say that your wording is acceptable so long as you explain somewhere how the modal peak is determined. Even for a histogram it depends on bin width (and origin (and  boundary conventions)). "as currently binned" puts the onus on the reader to focus on how you did it; on the contrary, you should explain anything unorthodox up front.

Comment: @Tim It may be a typo, but I must protest at the wording "a data". It's not idiomatic English and it's profoundly ambiguous as between "data set" and "data value".

Comment: Given Tim's comment is it then acceptable to say `"all points for which the distribution density is under 10% of the modal peak"` - provided I have stated the assumed shape of the distribution?

Comment: I would just say "estimated density". As soon as you start talking about "distribution density" you are going to confuse people who aren't clear about the difference between the distribution function and the density function (or not impress people who wonder whether you aren't clear).

Comment: That would include me! ... what you called distribution I would call cumulative distribution I think?

Comment: A full name would be "empirical cumulative distribution function", except that few people use all the words. "empirical" should be dropped if it's not estimated from data; "theoretical" could be inserted correspondingly.